# MPMoviePlayerController - modify m3u8 file before playing

Tags: encryption, mpmovieplayercontroller, m3u8

I have a URL for a m3u8 file. 
It lists all the .ts files which are encrypted using AES-128 encryption.
The m3u8 file also contains URI for the decryption keys.

Here's where it gets tricky.
The URI for the keys is inside a corporate firewall that my app can't access without a VPN. To solve this, I have a proxy server setup which can tunnel HTTP requests of my app to this URI, so this usable even outside the VPN.
I am trying to figure out a way I can replace the URI for the keys in the m3u8 file with my proxy servers URL and make it work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using NSURLProtocol and handling all HTTP requests made by the MPMoviePlayerController and tunneling them to my own web server.

Comment: Can you please share piece of code on how to achive decryption and play in  MPMoviePlayerController